# Angular 2 component inherit with onClick

Tags: html, typescript, angular2-template

I would like to inerit from component and add onClick method, how can I do it?
I want to have only **one** html file.
Here is a basic example -
I have a temple file with this html code-

```
<h1>h1</h1>
<h2>h2</h2>
```

I want to inherit this component and add OnClick method on h1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add that component  with function and a variable that sets to true on click.

```
<button (click)="toggleComponent()"></button>
<app-example-component *ngIf="variable">
```

ts:

```
variable = false;

toggleComponent() {

this.variable = !this.variable;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm looking for more nature solution. There's also a solution that I can add on click method to  h1 and implment it in one component and don't implment it in other. Do you know a nature solution?

Comment: @user1137582 What nature solution, I dont understand your question? if you want to show a component on click this is the way you do it. If you use one component on multiple places, it is good practice to create Shared folder and keep components u use multiple times inside it, and display them like in the example above.

Comment: My question wasn't to show component on click. I want use compnent twice and in one instace I want to have onclick method that does something.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend component like I did as below:

Plunker Link 
https://plnkr.co/edit/azixm9?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 (click)="callMe()">Hello {{name}}</h2>
       <comp-one></comp-one>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
  public callMe(compName: any): void {
    alert("App Component will handle this functionality")
  }
}



@Component({
  selector: 'comp-one',
  template: `<h2 (click)="callMe()">Click Me</h2>`,
})
export class ComponentOne extends App {

}
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, ComponentOne ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```